# Lookup table whose contents depend on size of integer type

Tags: c, c99

Suppose an function that should be portable to LP64 and ILP32 systems, i.e. `long int` can be 32 or 64 bits.  This function will have some table of constants, but the constants themselves need to be based on the width of type.  A contrived example:

```
// Find largest power of 1000 less than x, aka log base 1000 rounded down to an integer
unsigned long int intlog1000l(unsigned long int x) {
    const unsigned long int powers[] = {
        0, 1000, 1000000, 1000000000,
        1000000000000, 1000000000000000, 1000000000000000000 };
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(powers)/sizeof(*powers); i++)
        if (powers[i] > x) break;
    return i - 1; 
}
```

If `long int` is 64-bits, then this code works as intended.  But if `long int` is 32-bits, it will fail as the last three constants are too large to fit.

One way to work around this would be the change the function's interface and the table's type to both use `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`.  But how can this be combined with existing APIs that don't use those types, such as `__builtin_clzl()` or `labs()`?

Another alternative would be to keep the interface the same, but promote the argument inside the function to the largest size that will be supported, uint64_t, and keep store the table elements in this size.  But that is very inefficient on a 32-bit system.

One could arrange to provide a macro that defines the size of a long integer and then put the second line of the table inside an `#if`.  This is difficult since `sizeof()` is not available to preprocessor.  One needs something like autoconf to determine the size and generate a configuration header.  This is hard to fit into an existing build process.

In one intends to provide the full set of signed/unsigned `int`, `long int`, and `long long int` functions, here is another way:

```
unsigned int intlog1000(unsigned int); // assume 32 bits
unsigned long long int intlog1000ll(unsigned long long int); // assume 64 bits
static inline unsigned long int intlog1000l(unsigned long int x)
{ sizeof(x) == sizeof(unsigned int) ? intlog1000(x) : intlog1000ll(x); }
```

This make the assumption that it will be safe to assume to int and long long int are a certain size, and that long int will be equal in size to one or the other.  As this is the case on pretty much every 32-bit platform in current existence.

Is there some better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a series of `#if`

```
#include <limits.h>
const unsigned long int powers[] = {
    0, 1000, 1000000, 1000000000
    #if ULONG_MAX/1000 >= 1000000000
      , 1000000000000u
    #endif
    #if ULONG_MAX/1000 >= 1000000000000
      , 1000000000000000u
    #endif
    #if ULONG_MAX/1000 >= 1000000000000000
      , 1000000000000000000u
    #endif
    };
```

---

This above approach does has trouble as "macro math' is sometimes signed (based on experience, not spec), so below code makes the reasonable assumption that the max `unsigned long` is about 2x max `signed long`.  The "nested" approach is better as it insures that "macro math" works as it depends on the prior success.  This is not so important with C99,11 compilers as the math is at least 64-bits.  This makes more difference with older compilers or if one wanted to extend this scheme to even wider than 64-bit `unsigned long`.

```
    #if LONG_MAX/1000 >= 500000000
      , 1000000000000u
      #if LONG_MAX/1000 >= 500000000000
        , 1000000000000000u
        #if LONG_MAX/1000 >= 5000000000000000
          , 1000000000000000000u
          #if LONG_MAX/1000 >= 5000000000000000000
            #error powers[] needs extending
          #endif
        #endif
      #endif
    #endif
```

---

"macro math" or better *preprocessor arithmetic*, is done with at least 64-bit math in C11 (and likely C99), but only at least 32-bit with earlier like C89.

> For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation, all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, the types `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` defined in the header `<stdint.h>`.) This includes interpreting character constants, which may involve converting escape sequences into execution character set members.  C11 §6.10.1 4

Comment: This seems problematic.  If the implementation's `intmax_t` (or `uintmax_t` if the constants were unsigned) is not large enough to represent the constants on the right-hand side of the relational expressions, then I'm inclined to think that the relational expressions will not have the desired effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger See update.  Your concern is very valid.  The nested approach should address it.  We can be confident that the macro math works for at least 32 bit signed and then work our way up.

Comment: You can use integer suffixes in macro math

Comment: ... but only the `U` suffix really matters in preprocessor context.

Comment: @M.M Note: Spec "preprocessor arithmetic done in intmax_t/uintmax_t" C11 xv

Answer (score 0):

You could consider giving the table elements type `unsigned long long int` or `uintmax_t` (which may or may not be the same thing).  Any implementation that conforms to C99 or C11 will provide an `unsigned long long int` that is at least 64 bits wide, and therefore `uintmax_t` will also be at least that wide.

Of course, that begs the question of how your function can handle inputs larger than 64 bits.